# Represent a negative number in unsigned binary

Tags: binary

So I understand binary and its conversions, however I was presented with a question asking me to convert -100 to unsigned 8 bit binary. Would a valid answer just be to place a negative sign preceding my answer or should I explain that this cannot be done? No it is not asking for two's complement

Comment: What do you think **unsigned** means?

Comment: I think the OP knows what *unsigned* means, but is querying what the question given to him means by converting a -ve number to an *unsigned* 8-bit binary number.

Answer (score 0):

Without just giving you the answer, you should take the positive number of 100 (written as an 8-bit binary number) and then perform a 2s complement on the number.  Google "2s complement".  Your answer will comprise of 8 binary digits and the most significant digits (bit 7) will be a 1 (representing negative)

Comment: I know how to do two's complement. In fact, that is the second part of the question. I'm simply wondering if the question is illogical in its asking for an UNsigned answer.

Comment: In that case, yes it probably doesn't make sense.  It could be asking you to  take -100 and use 2s compliment to convert it to +100, OR it could be asking you what the number -100 (signed 8-bit) looks like if it was "treated as" an 8-bit unsigned number (-100 = 0x9C = 10011100 = 156d).  Ambiguous.